# Implementing of generic curried function using Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to implement generic function. JS analog of this function is:

```
const getFactory = (field) => (value) => ({ [field]: value })
```

use case:

```
// types
type Field1 = { field1: string }
type Field2 = { field2: boolean }
type Field3 = { field3: number }
type Field4 = { field4: boolean }
type Type1 = Field1 | Field2 | Field4
type Type2 = Field2 | Field3 | Field4

// use case
const field1Factory        = getFactory<Type1>('field1')
const field2Factory        = getFactory<Type1>('field2')
const field4Factory        = getFactory<Type1>('field4')

const anotherField2Factory = getFactory<Type2>('field2')
const field3Factory        = getFactory<Type2>('field3')
const anotherField4Factory = getFactory<Type2>('field4')

const typeField1        = field1Factory('test')       // { field1: 'test' }
const typeField2        = field2Factory(true)         // { field2: true }
const typeField4        = field4Factory(false)        // { field4: false }
const typeAnotherField2 = anotherField2Factory(false) // { field2: false }
const typeField3        = field3Factory(3)            // { field3: 3 }
const typeAnotherField4 = anotherField4Factory(true)  // { field4: true }
```

I supposed it maybe looks like this:

```
const getFactory = <Type extends {}>(field: keyof Type) => (value: Type[keyof Type]) => ({ [field]: value })
```

but when I trying to get factory (const field1Factory = getFactory('field1')) there is an Error:

```
Argument of type '"field1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kaya3 provided a great answer and explanation of the topics involved, however you can keep using union types instead of an intersection, by using conditional types do distribute over a union for extracting keys (`ExtractKeys`) and another conditional type (`ExtractValue`) to defer the resolution of the value type to call time enable to capture literal (e.g. `true` instead of `boolean`). If you don't need that, you can just use `T[K]` instead.

```js
type ExtractKeys<T> = T extends {} ? keyof T : never
type ExtractValue<T, K extends string | number | symbol> =
    T extends { [key in K]: infer U } ? U : never

const getFactory =
    <T>() =>
        <K extends ExtractKeys<T>>(field: K) =>
            <V extends ExtractValue<T, K>>(value: V) =>
                ({ [field]: value } as {[k in K]: V})
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `keyof` does not distribute over union types. You can verify this by inspecting `keyof Type1`:

```js
type KeyOfType1 = keyof Type1;
// KeyOfType1 = never
```

This happens because an object of type `(A | B)` is only guaranteed to have the keys in common to both `A` and `B`. But `Type1` is a union of objects with no keys in common, so there are no particular keys a `Type1` object is guaranteed to have.

So regardless of the type annotations on `getFactory`, this can't do what you want. You need to change `Type1` and `Type2` to intersection types. (If you need the original union types for something else, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/12299000) for a way to automatically construct the intersection type from the union type.)

```js
type Type1 = Field1 & Field2 & Field4
type Type2 = Field2 & Field3 & Field4
```

This works because  `keyof (A & B)` is equivalent to `(keyof A) | (keyof B)`, since an `A & B` object has the all the properties of `A` and `B` together in one object.

This fixes the type errors, but the resulting types aren't inferred as specifically as you want, even if we assert `{ [field]: value }` as the most specific type possible in the `getFactory` definition:

```js
const getFactory =
    <T>(field: keyof T) =>
        (value: T[keyof T]) =>
            ({ [field]: value } as { [K in keyof T]: T[K] })

const field1Factory = getFactory<Type1>('field1')

const typeField1 = field1Factory('test')

/* typeof typeField1 = {
    field1: string;
    field2: boolean;
    field4: boolean;
} */
```

This is because `field1Factory` is called with `T = Type1`, so its properties are `keyof Type1` which includes all three field names. To do better, you need another type parameter `K extends keyof T` for the field name, to infer which specific key of `T` is being used. You also want the more specific literal type `'test'` for the value, so you need a third type parameter `V extends T[K]` for this.

Unfortunately, when a function has multiple type parameters, you can't specify one and let the compiler infer the others. Either you have to write the string literal twice like `getFactory<Type1, 'field1'>('field1')`, or you can add another layer of currying:

```js
const getFactory2 =
    <T>() =>
        <K extends keyof T>(field: K) =>
            <V extends T[K]>(value: V) =>
                ({ [field]: value } as { [k in K]: V })

const field1Factory = getFactory2<Type1>()('field1')

const typeField1 = field1Factory('test')

/* typeof typeField1 = {
    field1: 'test';
} */
```

Note the extra `()` in `getFactory2<Type1>()('field1')`. But at least it infers the correct, most specific type without having to write the field name twice.

The type assertion `... as { [k in K]: V }` is necessary because `{ [field]: ... }` will be inferred as `[x: string]` even when `field` has the more specific type `K`.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygMQIbCiATgTxgXgCgYSYAeAFQD4AKAMwEsEAbAEwC4YBrBHEOmBQCUBKsVISaAN1TMArgk4UA2jz4CKAXRH4xE-aRoBvGMsYtWmzjPkIYAXxioIME8oDSMBmG69+gq0EPTQchQkJQSFhEFHRMXAAmAnESSlodPQNyTwQADygEMFYXNX9qeiY2TncMlKzUgDUYPIKilxV3TVobBU4G2vr641NzNkCeu0dnV1MuLx9OvtDwqBwABztkStYARgIZ0d3OaCxvOAdCVY2YLYsk-APthM4AIxAQZgRUH3tL9c3tgBmfYmQ6AzhgOQAWxeCCwFyuAIsABYQTBDsjXu9Pt8Ef9BP89g9bmw9gAyG5PGAUkmsZF-a4Uf73Sl3amstjAmnbekMuzuXgAeQED1KGkJ4QA9JKYHIIHZgM4EBFwNB0dsdmgMNg8FkHjEtfEcAlKIT0jQAOSHHYWsKRNWHBKGnX1fVIZ2JU0bHbmq1PW0qqLqlEe3UGN2xbWepne30YgOBtXfEBQAAWcNpTriLojoZNMYQCTj-rtqtgYNDrvg7uz0eZxYsgID9tgybTGZ5ldzteNXsLDbYyITLZgiNpez1wdJoctBWgtqy0seFh2nAtc6gFouI7HVMnjpnUCwChE9SXoKenCPCm3ZdH-1pqP3nZ79Fk8tPBnPU7pnDo78mRNYERABBMAU3TLBM32NtIMzGd-2YD8YG-R0-wA28g13RsqwrV9AU-QZUKBThgV+Hd-jAiCOxRGDwPbKCXyjHAaGvBBT2IlEr2PSYgA)

Comment: It is actually possible to keep current type annotation for `Type1` but using conditional types to extract field names: `type ExtractKeys<T> = T extends {} ? keyof T : never;` instead of saying `keyof T`

Comment: You help me a lot with such detailed explanation! Thanks!

Comment: @Dmitriy Good suggestion. However, I just tried replacing `K extends keyof T` with `K extends ExtractKeys<T>`, and I can't get it to infer `V` as anything other than `unknown` in the usage examples. The result is that the inferred types at the bottom end up as `string` and `boolean` instead of the more specific `'test'` and `true` literal types. If you can get it to work, I suggest writing it as an answer to the question. I think the intersection type is needed for the mapping `T[K]` even if you can get `K` without it.